# Is a two-way ANOVA always necessary for stimulus-evoked responses? (with specific example)

Tags: anova, two-way

**Is it always necessary to perform a two-way ANOVA for assessing differences between groups in response to a stimulus?**

One specific example: we look at the response of a nematode to a stimulus of 3% CO2.

In **the assay**,

1. worms are being exposed to 0% CO2 for three minutes,
2. then get challenged with a three minute 3% CO2 stimulus,
3. after which CO2 levels return to baseline.

A MATLAB script calculates the speed of these worms. Control worms speed up when exposed to CO2. We want to conclude whether mutant worms that lack specific proteins respond in the same way as control worms.

To me, the *response variable* is **speed**, one *independent variable* is **worm strain (mutant or control)**, the other *independent variable* is **stimulus/baseline**.

I would argue that to state that `worm strains respond differently to the stimulus`, you always need to perform a **two-way ANOVA** and state a *significant interaction effect* between the strain and stimulus variables: different worm strain respond differently to differing concentrations of CO2, or, a difference in speed increase (i.e. change) of worms depends on the strain.

Colleagues suggested only quantifying differences during the 3% CO2 interval. I would say that a **one-way ANOVA** allows you to state whether `the speed of different worm strains differs during the time in which worms were exposed to 3% CO2`, but that we cannot conclude anything about the *response* of worms to the stimulus, as a response infers a change in behaviour as compared to a baseline level, which is only included in two-way ANOVA.

This is a specific example to a general format of experiment that is often performed in the lab. Standard practices seem to differ across assays and field, which is why I am asking this possibly redundant question. Feel free to simply confirm whether my reasoning is right or wrong if you get annoyed by the simplicity of this question (, yet to my abilities, I didn't find a question that relates closely enough to mine on this platform).